# How to add 6 days and round to midnight for a series of date and times

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a data set of date and times that I wish to add 6 days to and round the time to midnight

My understanding is that midnight in R is regarded as 24:00 (please correct if I am wrong)

```
trial_A <- data.frame(study_ID=c(5, 6, 7, 8), 
             randomisation=as.POSIXlt(c("2021-01-01 11:00", "2021-01-02 10:00", 
                                        "2021-01-03 10:00", "2021-01-04 10:00")))
p <- days(6)
z <- hms("24:00:00")
final<- trial_A %>% mutate(randomisation_plus_6 = (randomisation + p))%>%
  mutate(randomisation_plus_6_date = (date(randomisation_plus_6)))%>%
  mutate(true_randomisation = (ymd_hms(paste(randomisation_plus_6_date,z))))
```

Essentially the output is the addition of 7 days as opposed to 6 days and rounding to midnight.

One solution would be to add 23:59:59 as opposed to 24:00:00

The desired outcome is to have the following output
true_randomisation
2021-01-07 24:00:00
2021-01-09 24:00:00
2021-01-10 24:00:00
2021-01-11 24:00:00

Thank you for any advice

Comment: Can you show the desired output?

Comment: Hi, thank you for reviewing my query. The desired outcome is to have the following output true_randomisation 2021-01-07 24:00:00 2021-01-09 24:00:00 2021-01-10 24:00:00 2021-01-11 24:00:00

Comment: I think 24:00 is being converted into 00:00 the following day.  Since the time appears the same in all, does it need retaining, or could you just work with dates instead of date-times?

Comment: with `lubridate` and with `asPOSIXct`  this `c <- c("2021-01-01 24:00:00", "2021-01-01 00:00:00")` will be in both cases converted to `"2021-01-02 CET" "2021-01-01 CET"`.  So `24:00:00` is already the next day - which is right. Maybe you should consider the last data of a day maybe in the last second of the day `23:59:59`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments - decided to go with 23:59:59